# Перенаправление с помощью Javascript

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте, появился вопрос.
Допустим, мы находимся на странице `/all.html`, на которой есть форма c кнопкой

```
<input type="text" id="sq" name="sq"><input type="submit" id="butt" name="sa" value="Ок">
```

Задача: пишем в поле слово, допустим, "яблоко", нажимаем на ok, и происходит переход на страницу `/all.html?q=Яблоко`.

Как реализовать подобное с помощью javascript? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду? Просто отправлять некие данные на сервер с помощью ajax или же [SPA подход](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application). В последнем случе всё завязано на [pushState](http://habrahabr.ru/post/123106/), либо fallback с хэшом `#` ([ибо IE < 10](http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate)).

Comment: А как-то проще? Допустим, получаем содержимое по клику на ок, его в переменную и после редирект на /all.html?q=переменная

Comment: @singmen т.е. делаем ajax-запрос **->** получаем данные **->** добавляем в `<content></content>` (тело сайта) + меняем иные блоки страницы, если это требуется **->** меняем URL. 

Вас такая последовательность интересует?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $("#butt").bind("click", function() {

  document.location.href="/all.html?q="+$("#sq").val();

 })
```

Как-то так, примерно.

P. S. Код пишу навскидку, так что возможны ошибки, но идея остается верной.

Answer (score 2):

Автор, может быть, вы имеете в виду это?

```
<form action="/all.html" method="get">
     <input name="q" />
     <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: да, именно, но то же яблоко переписывается как %FF%E1%EB%EE%EA%EE
как это можно исправить? чтоб было по-русски

Comment: @singmen, читаем и делаем выводы https://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/yandex-indexing/cyrillic-urls.xml

Comment: @mountpoint, используется это дело для страницы поиска, которая все равно не индексируется, так что оно необходимо именно так, иначе выдает 0 результатов

Comment: @singmen У Вас что на серверной стороне? И да, `%FF%E1%EB%EE%EA%EE` ни разу не яблоко.

Comment: @singmen и в чем проблема? У меня все ок. http://prntscr.com/68e2g6